# ARCore Recording

Tags: parsing, ffmpeg, mp4, arcore

i would like to access the track data and the custom data i record in my app.
can someone provide me the format that the different data tracks are saved in the mp4?
using this example  https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/recording_playback_java

Update:
i now know hot to extract the samples, but i don't know what is the structure of them.
can some one tell what is the structure ?

here are 2 consecutive gyro samples i am trying to parse:

0a 21 10 03 1d d3 a2 a7 3d 25 e6 31 70 3c 2d b3 2c d7 bc 30 89 ff e9 db cb bf 64 38 e1 bf 80 c6 d0 86 0c

0a 21 10 03 1d 4e 22 a5 3d 25 11 1c 87 3c 2d a9 2b d2 bc 30 f9 ca 8b de cb bf 64 38 9d d3 be c8 d0 86 0c

thanks :)

Comment: Your problem is how to decode the mp4 file to pose, imu, video, frame information at PC rather than using android API?

Comment: exactly, i know how to parse my custom data, but when i extract the accelerometer or the gyro samples, i dont know how to parse them and what values are kept.
for example, here are 2 gyro samples (where the camera doesnt move so much):
0a 21 10 03 1d d3 a2 a7 3d 25 e6 31 70 3c 2d b3 2c d7 bc 30 89 ff e9 db cb bf 64 38 e1 bf 80 c6 d0 86 0c  

0a 21 10 03 1d 4e 22 a5 3d 25 11 1c 87 3c 2d a9 2b d2 bc 30 f9 ca 8b de cb bf 64 38 9d d3 be c8 d0 86 0c

Comment: How could you determine which stream means gyr measurements?

Comment: Did you manage to find anything about the structure of those samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getUpdatedTrackData()` to retrieve the custom data recorded on a frame. It is possible to retrieve multiple track data from the same frame

The code to retrieve multiple track data is like this:

```
Collection<TrackData> trackDataList = frame.getUpdatedTrackData(trackUUID);
```

Once the `TrackData` is in a container object, extract the bytes of custom data.

```
for (TrackData trackData : trackDataList) {
  ByteBuffer bytes = trackData.getData(); // this is custom data
}
```

Comment: this is not what i mean, i am trying to parse the data in python, i know now how to achieve the samples of the gyro and accelerometer, but i don't know the structure of the sample